# Please help me to find what did I wrong in the question(Probability and distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$Q)$ There is rolling- a dice game following the rule.(Here the dice is average dice having sides $1$~$6$ )

- Game rule

  - Getting the number $6$ in one trial, We get $5$ points.
  - Otherwise getting the other numbers in one trial, We lose $1$ point.

If we doing this game $720$ times independently, Find the $a$ $s.t.$ $P(Z \geq a) $[continutiy correction is needed.]

(Here $P(Z \geq a) $ is a approximation of "Probability that total score is more than $60$" to the normal distribution.)

---

Here is my solution.

Let the $X_i$ be $i$ th trial ($1 \leq i \leq 720$) [Here the $X_i$ is a one trial at the $i$ th times. ]

Then, $E(X_i) =$ -$5 \over 6$ + $5 \over 6$ $= 0$, $V(X_i) = 5$

For $X =X_1 + X_2 +...+X_{720}$ [I.e. $X$ is variable for all the 720 times.], $E(X) = 0$ and $V(X) = 60^2$

Hence $X$~$N(0,(60)^2)$

Therefore considering $P(X \geq 59.5)$  by continuity correction of the $P(X \geq 60)$

Conclusion is  $P(Z \geq a) = P(Z \geq {59.5-0 \over 60})$, $a = {119 \over 120}$

I already knew the answer is $a=0.95$ not the above. I can't find which point I was wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $0.95$ would require the continuity correction to be $\pm 3$ rather than $\pm0.5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you seem to be correct.

$\mathsf E(X)=720\mathsf E(X_1)=720(5\cdot(-1)\cdot\tfrac 16+5\cdot\tfrac 16)=0$

$\mathsf{Var}(X)=720\mathsf{Var}(X_1)=720(5\cdot(-1)^2\cdot\tfrac 16+5^2\cdot\tfrac 16)=60^2$

$\therefore X\simeq\mathcal N(0,60^2)$

---

Then choose an appropriate correction value $\delta$.

$\mathsf P(X>60)\approx. \mathsf P(Z\geqslant\tfrac{60-\delta-0}{60})$

An aswer of $a=0.95$ would require $\delta$ to be $3$.  Why might this be so?

> Since the die result is either $-1$ or $5$ then $\delta$ is $\dfrac{5-(-1)}{2}$

Comment: Dear @Graham Kemp, Thanks for your answer why should I take $\delta = 3$  But If we take the  $\delta =0.5$, Does it incorrect? Because I've believed the $\delta$ should be "enough to small value", Mostly use $0.5$ when binary and normal. So is it more correct for the $\delta =0.5 $ than the $\delta = 3$?

Comment: We use a continuity correction because the values of $X$ are actually discrete rather than continuous.  $X$ is the sum of $720$ independent discrete random variables. If these were Bernoulli random variables (drawn from $\{0,1\}$) we would use a correction factor of $0.5$.  However, they are drawn from $\{-1,5\}$ so we use a correction factor of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Your error is in choosing $59.5$ for the continuity corrected value
- What are the possible scores in this dice game?
- The weak inequality  $P(X \ge 60)$ corresponds to which strong inequality $P(X \gt\, ??)$